# Self hosted fonts in email newsletter not showing locally

Tags: .htaccess, email, fonts, html-email

My brand uses a particular typeface, which I have bought and self host. I want to use the font on my email newsletter (with fall back fonts). Using @font-face I have linked to the self hosted fonts on my server. I've put the html newsletter file on my server and can see that the correct font is displayed. I've also sent myself a test email and again the correct font is displayed.

However, I'm writing the HTML file on my Mac and when I come to view the file (on my computer) in Firefox or Chrome the fall back font is displayed not the @font-face linked font. Why is this and what can I do about it? The link to fonts is absolute, so I presume it should work when testing locally. It is going to make development difficult if I can't test on my computer locally. Update: strangely when I open the html file on my computer in Safari the linked to fonts are displayed.

Update: is this something to do with .htaccess file? See  http://ijotted.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/self-hosting-web-fonts-for-use-on-your.html  "IE and Firefox require that fonts be served from the same domain as the website" Browsers are not able to access the files because the files are stored on my server (not on my computer)?

Code here:

```
@media screen {  
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'ElenaWebBasic';
        src: url('http://www.xyz.co.uk/webfonts/ElenaWebBasicRegular/ElenaWebBasicRegular.eot');
        src: url('http://www.xyz.co.uk/webfonts/ElenaWebBasicRegular/ElenaWebBasicRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('http://www.xyz.co.uk/webfonts/ElenaWebBasicRegular/ElenaWebBasicRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('http://www.xyz.co.uk/webfonts/ElenaWebBasicRegular/ElenaWebBasicRegular.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, it's difficult to test custom fonts if you have them installed on your system. When a browser or email client sees a font in the font stack, it can display the locally installed version if the remotely referenced one fails. So even though it's broken, it will seem like it works. For email, using a remote service like Litmus or Email on Acid is a good way to test emails and web font display.

Depending on what where you purchased the font, they might have a way to reference it on a CDN. Referencing a service (like Google fonts) is currently the easiest way to display web fonts in html email.

```
<!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
<!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. -->
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href='https://place-you-bought-the-font.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I'd recommend looking in the font seller's site to see if they have an option like this.

Here are [a few more options](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/web-fonts-in-email/) to try:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen {
   @font-face{
       font-family:'Open Sans';
       font-style:normal;
       font-weight:400;
       src:local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff') format('woff');
   }
}
</style>
```

Email has trouble with `@import`, so you might try using `<link>` instead:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Hi. @font-face correctly links to the self hosted fonts, but not when I view the html file on my computer in a browers, making development difficult. It only seems to work when the html file is on my server (rather than on my computer), this seems odd behaviour.

Comment: @Markeee Can you update your question with a code sample of how you're referencing the font?